# Should I use Workflow or fsYacc?

Tags: f#, workflow, fsyacc, fparsec, fslex

I have a very simple DSL I need to parse on a .Net platform. Not being very experienced with parsers, I have been looking at examples using F# (fsLex, fsYacc, FParsec). I am not that familiar with F#, but do have some experience with Workflow and LINQ.

Given the simplicity of the DSL, I can get away with using LINQ to implement the lexer. Workflow (I would be using V4) is appealing to implement the grammar, since I am more familiar with it, it's easier to explain to others given its graphic nature, and it is supported by Microsoft and will continue to evolve, presumably.

If my DSL becomes more sophisticated, however, I can image the WF implementation becoming a nested hell of activities and a LINQ based lexer going the same way. At that point learning F# and using one of the F# tools would make more sense.

I am wondering if others have compared WF and F# parsing tools to implement a simple DSL interpreter and what the conclusions might be.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to give an answer without knowing a little more about what the DSL is supposed to do and how complex it may get in the future. If your DSL is about workflow then WF would seem like a very logical choice to store your parsed results in.

If your language is not too complex then LINQ or a handrolled little parser could very well do. It's good to keep it simple and use tooling that your colleagues know.

When your language becomes more complicated however this approach tends to come apart pretty quickly. But on the upside, you can just switch your parser then. Don't solve problems you may never have.

Personally I really like FParsec for parsing. It requires some knowledge about F# but when you've got your head around it it is so insanely powerful for turning text into AST, and it's very lean in that there are no 'magical steps' that turns your EBNF into gibberish code, you can see how it works and tune it.

When you don't have time to dive into F# and FParsec there's also [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) which is like FParsec but then for C#.

This is what I can say from what you've told us, if you have any concrete issues let us know.

Rgds GJ